# elasticsearch minimum buckets count

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to get results on an aggregation where buckets.length (number / count of buckets) has a minimum count, kind of like HAVING in SQL.

(In this particular scenario site visitors who have visited at-least 5 different days.)

A portion of my query:

```
"aggs": {
    "site_visitors": {
        "aggs": {
            "users": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "user_id",
                    "size": 0
                },
                "aggs": {
                    "daily_counts": {
                        "date_histogram": {
                            "field": "timestamp",
                            "interval": "1d"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here we have a bucket with 5 results (buckets.length). Most buckets won't have 5 or more results and I don't want all of those.

```
{
     "key": 123456,
     "doc_count": 10,
     "days_count": {
        "buckets": [
             {
                "key_as_string": "2017-04-05T00:00:00.000Z",
                "key": 1491350400000,
                "doc_count": 2
             },
             {
                "key_as_string": "2017-04-22T00:00:00.000Z",
                "key": 1492819200000,
                "doc_count": 1
             },
             {
                "key_as_string": "2017-04-25T00:00:00.000Z",
                "key": 1493078400000,
                "doc_count": 4
             },
             {
                "key_as_string": "2017-04-30T00:00:00.000Z",
                "key": 1493510400000,
                "doc_count": 2
             },
             {
                "key_as_string": "2017-05-04T00:00:00.000Z",
                "key": 1493856000000,
                "doc_count": 1
             }
        ]
     }
}
```

I want to get results that ONLY have at-least 5 results or more (eg: gte) in each bucket - not the doc_count, but the buckets.length.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can add the `"min_doc_count": 5` parameter in your `date_histogram` aggregation.

```
"aggs": {
    "site_visitors": {
        "aggs": {
            "users": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "user_id",
                    "size": 0
                },
                "aggs": {
                    "daily_counts": {
                        "date_histogram": {
                            "field": "timestamp",
                            "interval": "1d"
                        }
                    },
                    "min_5_buckets_selector": {
                        "bucket_selector": {
                           "buckets_path": {
                              "count": "daily_counts._bucket_count" 
                           },
                           "script": {
                              "inline": "params.count >= 5"
                           }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In this case, I think the min_doc_count will relate to the number of _documents_ within a bucket object, but doesn't relate to the number of _objects_ within the bucket - that's what I'm aiming for - the number of objects within the bucket (each object could have a varied number of docs which is fine).

Comment: In buckets, you have documents, not sure what you mean by "object"

Comment: Structurally the buckets is an array of objects. Each object has a doc_count.  `min_doc_count` will apply to the number of docs, but not the number of buckets. I don't think there is a `min_bucket_count`... but that'd be what I'm looking for - and I don't think that exists.

Comment: The number of buckets in your case is defined by the number of days for which documents exist

Comment: _"The number of buckets in your case is defined by the number of days for which documents exist"_.  YES! Thank you, Val. That's probably a simpler way of stating it. So, what I'm trying to return is only results with 5+ days worth of results.

Comment: If you're using ES5, you can try using a `bucket_selector` pipeline aggregation. See my updated answer.

Comment: @jr71this works, would you mind accepting the answer. +1 from me